# connect cUrl to api: can not use response as JSON

Tags: php, json, ajax, curl

using the following cUrl PHP (with x-api-key validation) after form submit which runs nicely and connects to API:

```
private function handlePostRequests($args = array()) {
    // A sample PHP Script to POST data using cURL
    $headers = array(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization',
        'x-api-key: xxxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    );
    $post_data = '{
        "user_email": "'.stripslashes($_POST['email']).'",
        "user_firstname": "'.stripslashes($_POST['personName']).'",
    }';
        
    // Prepare new cURL resource
    $crl = curl_init('https://exampleapi.com/api');
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);   
    // Set HTTP Header for POST request 
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        
    // Submit the POST request
    $result = curl_exec($crl);
    $data = json_encode($result);
    print_r ($data);
    echo ($data);

    // close the request
    curl_close($crl);
}
```

**Although from here I'd like to redirect the user to the URL returned by the API (site_creation_url) with .ajax() in javascript when a form is submitted on success:**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: location.href,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    ajaxRequest: 1,
                },
                success: function (data) { // doesnt run as success
                    console.log('yes result', data);
                    console.log('site_url',data.site_creation_url);
                },
                error: function (data) {  // returns the json but not not in a json format
                    console.log('no result', data);
                    console.log('site_url',data.site_creation_url);
                },
```

This unfortunately returns error and site_url as undefined, although I get the response from the API in the console (partial response because its too long):

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ (e)
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ (e)
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
error: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (e)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (e)
readyState: 4
responseText: "\"{\\\"errors\\\":[],\\\"messages\\\":[],\\\"site_creation_url\\\":\\\"https:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/trial.site.com\\\\\\/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ2ZXJpZmljYXRpb25fY29kZSI6eyJpZCI6InN0cmluZyIsInZhbHVlIjoic3RyaW5nIn1dfX0.MCNRMhklGLnkUMjWXWof4K8Rflad7xL_GYnNBmi7pxM\\\"}\"\"{\\\"errors\\\":[],\\\"messages\\\":
```

I believe this is due to the cUrl response is not JSON or maybe I'm having a bigger error in the logic of this flow. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are double encoding the response:

```
$data = json_encode($result);
```

Where you want to decode it instead (`json_decode()`) to use it within PHP, or simply forward it as is (it's already JSON).

Also this is unsafe:

```
$post_data = '{
    "user_email": "'.stripslashes($_POST['email']).'",
    "user_firstname": "'.stripslashes($_POST['personName']).'",
}';
```

Instead use native `json_encode()`:

```
$post_data = json_encode([
    'user_email' => $_POST['email'],
    'user_firstname' => $_POST['personName'],
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although when removing the line '$data = json_encode($result);' it still returns the same output from .ajax() error

Comment: @user3615851 it's impossible to get the same output after changing the output